# NavigationLink is not affected by EditButton

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, swiftui, swiftui-navigationlink

I have a form that includes a NavigationLink and I'm expecting it to be enabled (tappable) after tapping the EditButton, but that's not happening. This is my code:

[image]

Comment: One thing I would suggest is moving the `Form` into a custom subview, into which you move all your navigation links and, crucially, the `.editMode` environment variable – leaving the `EditButton()` in the higher-level `DraftUI` view. I've found that gives much more reliable behaviour in reading the edit mode.

Comment: I tried. Nothing changed.

Answer (score 0):

Replace this

```
editMode?.wrappedValue.isEditing != true
```

to

```
editMode?.wrappedValue == .inactive
```

Comment: it doesn't work